Mobile Website behaves differently in chrome when launched from an "Add To Home Screen" icon
On an Android device, if open chrome and type in my website the website works fine. Now I use the "Add To Home Screen" option from mobile chrome.  Launching my website from the icon now on my home screen, the website will fail to launch.
The issue is a cookie my website uses. First request creates a cookie and sends it with the response. Any subsequent requests pass the cookie to the server. The cookie is used as a breadcrumb and passed to the SSO provider.
The cookie is SameSite=strict.
The cookie is considered OK when the website is launched directly from chrome.
The cookie is considered not in the same domain when my website is launched from the short cut created by chrome.
I've used the chrome desktop tools to remote monitor the chrome sessions on the android device. I can see that chrome is not passing the cookie in the shortcut case. With the message about the cookie domain being different even though the website and cookie domain match.
